# How to choose the order of PivotItems?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a PivotItem added dynamically and another 2 PivotItems which are added from the designer. I would like to place the one added dynamically first (First from the left).

```
 <Pivot Name="EntryPivot" Title="Gym Crew" Background="Azure">
        <Pivot.RightHeader>
            <CommandBar>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Import" Label="Import" Click="ImportCsv_Button"/>
                <AppBarSeparator/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Delete"/>
                <AppBarSeparator/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="Save"/>
            </CommandBar>
        </Pivot.RightHeader>
        <PivotItem Header="View Progress">

        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Progress Charts">

        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

Or at least, upon enetring the application, the dynamically added PivotItem is shown.

```
private void addElements()
{
    calendar = getTheBloodyCalendar();
    pivot = EntryPivot;

    Grid calendarGrid = new Grid()
    {
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
    };
    calendarGrid.Children.Add(calendar);

    calendarItem = new PivotItem()
    {
        Header = "Calendar",
        Content = calendarGrid
    };

    pivot.Items.Add(calendarItem); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Insert method for inserting at a particular index

```
pivot.Items.Insert(0, calendarItem);
```